# create "ArrayList" in xml resource file in android

Tags: java, android, xml

I know how to create a simple Array in xml like this

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="countries_array">
        <item>Afghanistan</item>
        <item>Albania</item>
        <item>Algeria</item>
        <item>American Samoa</item>
        <item>Andorra</item>
        <item>Angola</item>
        <item>Anguilla</item>
        <item>Antarctica</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And then I initialize it like this in code

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = 
        new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries_array);
textView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But I want to store more items than just a string, so I need a way to store an arraylist rather than a simple array.

Like below

```
<resources>
<Share>
    <name>Apple</name>
    <currentRate>5.69</currentRate>
    <changeToday>-0.11</changeToday>
    <changeTodayPercent>-0.02</changeTodayPercent>
    <timeUpdated>2012,12,06,18,00,00</timeUpdated>
<Share>
<Share>
    <name>Microsoft</name>
    <currentRate>5.88</currentRate>
    <changeToday>0.19</changeToday>
    <changeTodayPercent>+0.09</changeTodayPercent>
    <timeUpdated>2012,12,06,18,00,00</timeUpdated>
<share>
...
</resources>
```

I already have a class called Share.java with following variables that need to be set via setMethods

public class ShareHolding {

```
private String name;
private double currentRate;
private double changeToday;
private double changeTodayPercent;
private GregorianCalendar timeUpdated;
}
```

and add them to an arraylist

```
ArrayList<Share> allShares = new ArrayList<Share>();

allShares.getShare(0).setName("I want to access my xml file here and add the first shares name here");
```

Comment: I'd consider using JSON and save all the shares as a JSON array of JSON objects saved as a single String resource. You would have to create your own way of parsing it however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you won't be able to mismatch data types using the resource file. The resource only supports  [one-way datatypes.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) e.g Array of string, array of integers, etc.

The best solution that would work is to make the Share xml into it's own file and parse is into your shared object. [The android developer has some example of the built in xml parser](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)